SVG to PNG in Laravel makes jagged/crisped edges of product
if ($extension === 'svg') {
    $svgIsWorking = env('SVG_ACTIVATED', true);
    $fileNamePngSvg = 'shape_' . str_replace('_svg', '', $type) . '.png';
    $command = 'rsvg-convert "' . $storagePath . $image . '" > "' . $storagePath . $filePath . '/' . $fileNamePngSvg . '"';
    exec($command);
}

I am trying to convert svg to png, and then fill with color, and this is what is happening. Edges of products are very crisped/jagged and it looks very bad.

I tried to change density but nothing is changed. What else could I try?
$density = 1000; // Set the desired density (DPI)
$command = 'rsvg-convert --dpi-x=' . $density . ' --dpi-y=' . $density . ' "' . $storagePath . $image . '" -o "' . $storagePath . $filePath . '/' . $fileNamePngSvg . '"';


FYI: How do I format my posts?
